# Why would it count for Abu touching the gem when the cave was talking to Aladdin?

Tags: aladdin

Abu and Aladdin enter the Cave of Wonders and it tells ALADDIN not to touch anything but the lamp (meaning don't touch anything with the intent to steal.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you know it was talking *only* to Aladdin, and not to the both of them?

Comment: Also in many cases (both real world and in stories), not knowing the rules doesn’t mean the rules don’t apply. Even if the voice was talking to Alladin only, the consequences for anyone touching anything but the lamp likely apply no matter what.

Answer (score 5):

### Them's the rules

The Cave of Wonders in Disney's *Aladdin* is enforcing a rule that appears in other fiction: lots of "decoy" treasure is offered to the visitor, but it's all just a trap -- the only item of real value is the unique item at the end.

Often, the reason for this arrangement is to weed out the unworthy: you don't want your powerful artifact to fall into the hands of any person who can be distracted from their important quest by opportunities for mere personal gain. Such a person is likely to succumb to the temptation to use the artifact to enrich themselves. So, it's basically a screening process. "The successful candidate will abstain from pursuing their personal self-interest."

So it appears to be with the Cave of Wonders. No explanation is offered for why the Cave is animate, or why the magic lamp would be inside the Cave. Whatever the reason, all the other goods inside the Cave are decoys. That means they're off-limits to anyone.

---

It is not obvious that the Cave is speaking only to Aladdin. It does not address him specifically. And even if it were, the advice to ignore the other treasure is not *merely* some special condition the Cave decided to apply only to Aladdin.

While he was in the cave, Abu demonstrated that he doesn't have the clarity of purpose, or even the *attention span*, to follow simple advice. This is a character flaw: it's not that Abu is bad, simply that he's not *as good* as Aladdin.

The truth is that Aladdin should have known that Abu was unruly and disobedient, and immediately recognized there was no way Abu would abide by *any* rules whatsoever. If he'd had half a brain in his head, he would have left Abu outside the Cave.